# Approximate rank of the set formed by all delayed replicas of a bandlimited signals between 0 and T

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, manifolds, signal-analysis

Given a complex-valued signal with a certain delay $s(t-\tau)$ for which we sample $N$ instants
$$
  \mathbf{s(\tau)}=\left[s(0-\tau),\ldots,s\left(\frac{N-1}{f_s}-\tau\right)\right]^T
$$
at Nyquist rate $f_s\geq 2B$, and such signal is band-limited, i.e.
$$
  S(f)=FT\{s(t)\}=0 \quad\text{for} \quad |f| > B.
$$
Is there any result that sheds some light on the approximate dimension of the following set?:
$$
  \mathcal{U}=\left\{\mathbf{s}(\tau):0\leq\tau\leq T\right\}
$$
In other words, is $\mathcal{U}$ (approximately) a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^N$ no matter what is the signal $s(t)$? And if yes, what is the dimension?

Thank you

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to increase
the visibility of this question.

Comment: Can you give an example of tag?

Comment: I am not familiar with the topic of your question, so I'm not sure -- maybe one (or some) of the following fit: ca.analysis-and-odes fa.functional-analysis na.numerical-analysis